# Feeding input to resnet18 onnx model (Resnet18 deployment for object detction in video file)

Tags: python, neural-network, resnet, onnx, onnxruntime

I have built and saved a trained resnet18 model using the code in github in [this link](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/imagenet/main.py)

the code can be run by specifying the training directory and type of network model.

the model resnet18.onnx is chosen and trained to classify 4 types of cells.

I am using Nvidia jetson (ubuntu) for this project.

now i need to use the generated trained model from the code above (resnet18.onnx)to classify objects in video using the following snippet code where a small box and the value of prediction is displayed on the detected cell in the video.

the error message i get when i run the above code using the resnet18.onnx is

> confidences, boxes = ort_session.run(None, {input_name: img})
>
> ort_session.run   expected 2 get 1

what is the second input that is expected by the onnx model(i know that the model needs only the image to classify it so what is the second input that is required)

Answer (score -1):

The error means the model expects 2 inputs and you only provided one.